# Reshape Matlab table

Tags: matlab

I have the following table

```
name = ['A' 'A' 'A' 'B' 'B' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'D' 'D' 'E' 'E' 'E']';
value = randn(14, 1);
T = table(name, value);
```

i,e.

```
T = 

name      value  
____    _________

A       0.0015678
A        -0.76226
A         0.98404
B         -1.0942
B         0.71249
C           1.688
C          1.4001
C         -0.9278
C         -1.3725
D         0.11563
D        0.076776
E          1.0568
E          1.1972
E         0.29037
```

I want to transform it in the following way: take the first two cells in `value` corresponding to different values in `name` and put it in the `5x2` matrix. This matrix would have rows corresponding to different names `A,B,C,D,E` and columns corresponding to `values`, e.g. the first two rows are

```
0.0015678 -0.76226
-1.0942    0.71249
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) using a custom function. The first step is to convert the `name` column of `T` into a numeric vector; and then `accumarray` can be applied.

This approach requires `T` being sorted according to column 1, because only in this case is `accumarray` guaranteed to preserve order (as indicated in its documentation). So if `T` may not be sorted (although it is in your example), sort it first using [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html).

```
T = sortrows(T, 1); %// you can remove this line if T is guaranteed to be sorted
[~, ~, names] = unique(T(:,1)); %// names as a numeric vector
result = cell2mat(accumarray(names, T.value, [], @(x) {x([1 2]).'}));
```

Comment: Very nice job with `accumarray`! Didn't think about using it here.

Answer (score 3):

First figure out where each name has values located in the table, then cycle through each name and place the first two values encountered for each name into individual cell arrays.  Once you're done, reshape the matrix to `5 x 2` as you have said.  As such, do something like this:

```
names = unique(T.name); %// 1
ind = arrayfun(@(x) find(T.name == x), names, 'uni', 0); %// 2
vals = cellfun(@(x) T.value(x(1:2)), ind, 'uni', 0); %// 3
m = [vals{:}].'; %// 4
```

Let's go through each line of code slowly.

---

## Line #1

The first line finds all **unique** names through [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and we store them into `names`.

## Line #2

The next line goes through all of the unique names and finds those locations / rows in the table that share that particular name.  I use [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) and go through each name in `names`, find those rows that share the same name as one we are looking for, and place those row locations into individual cells; these are stored into `ind`.  To find the locations of each valid name in our table, I use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) and the locations are placed into a column vector.  As such, we will have five column vectors where each column vector is placed into an individual cell.  These column vectors will tell us which rows match a particular name located in your table.

## Line #3

The next line uses [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to go through each of the cells in `ind` and extracts the first two row locations that share a particular name, indexes into the `value` field for your table to pull those two values, and these are placed as two-element vectors into individual cells for each name.

## Line #4

The last line of code simply unrolls each two-element vector.  The first two elements of each name get stored into **columns**.  To get them into rows, I simply transpose the unrolling.  The output matrix is stored into `m`.

---

If you want to see what the output looks like, this is what I get when I run the above code with your example table:

```
m =

    0.0016   -0.7623
   -1.0942    0.7125
    1.6880    1.4001
    0.1156    0.0768
    1.0568    1.1972
```

Be advised that I only showed the first 5 digits of precision so there is some round-off at the end.  However, this is only for display purposes and so what I got is equivalent to what your expect for the output.

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you want use the tables, you could try something like this:

```
count = 1;
U = unique(table2array(T(:,1)));
for ii = 1:size(U,1)
   A = find(table2array(T(:,1)) == U(ii));
   A = A(1:2);
   B(count,1:2) = table2array(T(A,2));
   count = count + 1;
end
```

Personally, I would find this simpler to do with your name and value arrays and forget about the table.  If it is a requirement then I understand, however I will provide my solution still.  It may provide some insight either way.

```
count = 1;
U = unique(name);
for ii = 1:size(U,1)
   A = find(name == U(ii));
   A = A(1:2);
   B(count,1:2) = value(A);
   count = count + 1;
end
```

Quick and dirty, but hopefully it's good enough.  Good luck.

Comment: The second approach is pretty much what I did, but I decided to stay within the constraints of a `table` and use dot notation to reference the corresponding fields.  +1 btw.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that is more manageable and easily scalable exists. Since MATLAB R2013b you can use a specialized function for pivoting a table (which is what you want to do): [`unstack`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unstack.html).

In order to get exactly what you wanted, you need to add an extra variable to your table that will indicate replications:

```
name = ['A' 'A' 'A' 'B' 'B' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'D' 'D' 'E' 'E' 'E']';
value = randn(14, 1);
rep = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3];
T = table(name, value, rep);

T = 

name      value      rep
____    _________    ___

A         0.53767    1  
A          1.8339    2  
A         -2.2588    3  
B         0.86217    1  
B         0.31877    2  
C         -1.3077    1  
C        -0.43359    2  
C         0.34262    3  
C          3.5784    4  
D          2.7694    1  
D         -1.3499    2  
E          3.0349    1  
E          0.7254    2  
E       -0.063055    3
```

Then you just use `unstack` like this:

```
pivotTable = unstack(T, 'value','name')

pivotTable = 

    rep       A          B          C           D           E    
    ___    _______    _______    ________    _______    _________

    1      0.53767    0.86217     -1.3077     2.7694       3.0349
    2       1.8339    0.31877    -0.43359    -1.3499       0.7254
    3      -2.2588        NaN     0.34262        NaN    -0.063055
    4          NaN        NaN      3.5784        NaN          NaN
```

Afterwards, it's a matter of [re-arranging the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744544/how-to-transpose-a-matlab-table) if you still want to.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to first convert the table into a matrix form and then reshape it by using the "reshape" function in Matlab.

```
matrix = t{:,:};% t-- your table variable
reshape_matrix = reshape(matrix ,[2,3]) % [2,3]--> the size of the matrix you desire
```

These two steps can be done by one line of code

```
reshape_matrix = reshape(t{:,:},[2,3]);
```