# How to transpose a MATLAB table?

Tags: matlab

How can I flip a table such that `VariableNames` becomes `RowNames`

i.e.

```
   m0         m1         m10        m11        m12        m13        m14        m2         m3         m4          m5          m6         m7         m8         m9   
    ________    _______    _______    _______    _______    _______    _______    _______    _______    _______    ________    ________    _______    _______    _______

    0.096898    0.11567    0.23266    0.11393    0.51438    0.51438    0.51438    0.42039    0.11543    0.11024    0.060229    0.086558    0.11542    0.11537    0.43305
```

becomes

```
        Chisq
        _______
m0       0.096898
m1        0.11567
m2        ...
...       ...
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you need to first convert your table to an Array before rotating and converting it back into a table:

```
YourArray = table2array(YourTable);
YourNewTable = array2table(YourArray.');
YourNewTable.Properties.RowNames = YourTable.Properties.VariableNames;
```

You can also try `rot90(YourTable)` and see what happens, but I'm not sure it does the same (I think it is one of those misleading names)

Comment: This could be shortened to `NewTable = table(YourTable{:,:}.',...
    'RowNames',YourTable.Properties.VariableNames)`. `rot90` does not accept tables.

Comment: If your table had Names for the row, add this line: `YourNewTable.Properties.VariableNames = YourTable.Properties.RowNames;`

Comment: I have done the same. My variables are of different datatypes (uint8, float32 etc.). When I create the new table, all variables are cast to uint16. How can i avoid this ?

Comment: @EBH this put the old table fully in the first variable of the new table. I don't think there is a getting aroudn the array2table function

Answer (score 0):

```
function [tableTransposed] = transposeTable(tableIn)
%this function transposes a table. 
props =tableIn.Properties.VariableNames;

tableTransposed = table();
tableSz = size(tableIn);
tableTransposed.metricName = props';
tableTransposed(1,:) = [];
for newPropertyNum = 1:tableSz(1)
    propCurr = table2array(tableIn(newPropertyNum,1));
    if isa(propCurr,'numeric')
        newProperty = num2str( propCurr );
    else %assumed to be string
        newProperty = propCurr;

    end
    tableTransposed = setfield(tableTransposed,newProperty,table2array(tableIn(newPropertyNum,2:end))');
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As of MATLAB R2018a, you can also use the [ROWS2VARS function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rows2vars.html).
I have found that this function adds an additional column called `OriginalVariableNames` to the table, which might not be what you want.