# Transpose table of double and int64 values without int64 conversion

Tags: matlab, transpose

I have a table with int64 and double values (let' name it X) in Matlab and I want to transpose it. X' causes that error:  *'Error using  '  (line 213) Undefined function 'ctranspose' for input arguments of type 'table'.  Use the ROWS2VARS function instead.'* But when I use the **rows2vars** function all the table elements are cast to int64. Here is an example. The table :

```
 B1        B2      B3
_____    _____    _____

1.73      3.4       5  
1.95      3.2       3  
2.38      3.3       2  
1.44     3.75       7  
   5      3.5       1  
4.75      3.4       1  
 2.1      3.2       3  
 3.2      3.4       2  
2.25     3.25       2  
 1.3     5.25       9
```

gets transposed but looks like that:

```
OriginalVariableNames    Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4    Var5    Var6    Var7    Var8    Var9    Var10
_____________________    ____    ____    ____    ____    ____    ____    ____    ____    ____    _____

      {'B365H'}           2       2       2       1       5       5       2       3       2        1  
      {'B365D'}           3       3       3       4       4       3       3       3       3        5  
      {'B365A'}           5       3       2       7       1       1       3       2       2        9
```

I understand that this happens because (as written in Mathworks documentation) "If you combine integers with double, single, or logical classes, all elements of the resulting matrix are given the data type of the left-most integer". I have also used the **table2array** function to transfrom the table into a matrix before transposing, but then again all doubles are converted to int64.

Is there a way to transpose the table but keep all the double values as they are?

Comment: What  about table2cell and cell2table ?

Comment: Have you checked the second answer to this question? It may work as it does it row by row: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744544/how-to-transpose-a-matlab-table

Comment: It looks like going on a per-column basis should work; preallocate a table to the transposed size, then for each column cast it to an array of the relevant type, transpose that (use `.'`, not `'`), then go back to table representation and store on the correct row.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, there are only 2 answers to the question you link so finding the one you reference should be easy but for more densely populated question/answers you can link directly to a specific answer. For example I think the one you meant was: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41245236/3460361

Comment: @Hoki thanks. I just copied the wrong link, and it was too late to edit when I realized.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you want to keep the new row with the `double` values storing them as doubles, and the new row with int64s still being `int64`? You can't do that (unless you do something ugly like convert them to cells), because columns in Matlab `table`s are homogeneously typed.

If you want them to both end up as doubles, then just explicitly convert your `int64` column to double before doing the conversion. Unlike in most programming languages, in Matlab, when you do mixed-mode arithmetic or concatenation, *doubles implicitly narrow to ints, instead of ints widening to double*, for obscure historical reasons.