# How can I efficiently pivot a table with replications in MATLAB from tall to wide format?

Tags: matlab, pivot

I have a tall [MATLAB table](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) like this:

```
spam = 

   Data             cat1         cat2         time
__________          ___________  __________   ______    

  -0.41763          1            0            0
   0.11719          1            0            0
  ...               ...          ...          ...
  -0.16546          1            0            1   
  ...               ...          ...          ...
  -0.21763          1            0            2   
   0.31719          2            0            0 
  ...               ...          ...          ...
   0.58116          3            1            0 
  ...               ...          ...          ...
```

`Data` is of double format, `cat1` (8 levels) and `cat2` (3 levels) are categorical, and `time` (3 levels) is ordinal (but could be double). Each time point of each `cat1` and `cat2` level includes 30 (technical) replicates (denoted by `...` above).

I wish to use these data in [`fitrm`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitrm.html?searchHighlight=fitrm), which requires them in the wide format. Hence I need to transform the `Data` column to three separate variables.

Using `unstack` I get something like this:

```
spam = unstack(spam, 'Data', 'time')
Warning: Variable names were modified to make them valid MATLAB identifiers. 

spam = 
cat1       cat2        x0             x1         x2   
______    _________    ___________    _______    ________

1         0            -7.6605e-15     2.3168     0.45234
2         0             6.2172e-15     5.1661     24.89
3         1             8.8818e-16     56.697     40.441
4         1            -7.9936e-15    -22.741    -17.191
5         1            -1.4433e-15    -7.7803    -20.817
6         2             5.5511e-16     7.8535    -0.21172
7         2             5.3291e-15     13.658     5.8402
8         2             2.2204e-15     9.1739     13.814
```

Obviously this result does not include all the information in the tall table.
Specifically, the replicates have not been carried to the result.

Using `accumarray`, in a similar fashion to that shown [in another stack page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642838/reshape-matlab-table/27643539#27643539) could be promising, but in my case it seemed easier to perform the one-time transformation by hand.

Is anyone aware of a more efficient approach?

Answer (score 0):

I realize now that perhaps the easiest way is to just add an extra variable `replication` in the tall table and then use [`unstack`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unstack.html) as above.

Example (with different data, taken from [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39769842/6888231)):

```
name = ['A' 'A' 'A' 'B' 'B' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'D' 'D' 'E' 'E' 'E']';
value = randn(14, 1);
rep = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3];
T = table(name, value, rep);

T = 

name      value      rep
____    _________    ___

A         0.53767    1  
A          1.8339    2  
A         -2.2588    3  
B         0.86217    1  
B         0.31877    2  
C         -1.3077    1  
C        -0.43359    2  
C         0.34262    3  
C          3.5784    4  
D          2.7694    1  
D         -1.3499    2  
E          3.0349    1  
E          0.7254    2  
E       -0.063055    3  



pivotTable = unstack(T, 'value','name')

pivotTable = 

    rep       A          B          C           D           E    
    ___    _______    _______    ________    _______    _________

    1      0.53767    0.86217     -1.3077     2.7694       3.0349
    2       1.8339    0.31877    -0.43359    -1.3499       0.7254
    3      -2.2588        NaN     0.34262        NaN    -0.063055
    4          NaN        NaN      3.5784        NaN          NaN
```

Comment: If you are going to self answer your question, it needs more information than a link to another answer.

Comment: Thanks for informing me on etiquette @AnderBiguri. I have added an example in my answer.